# typoscriptObjectPath throws error in Powermail 12

Tags: typo3, powermail, typo3-12.x

TYPO3 12.4, Powermail 12.2.1:

the following cObject in Mail to User or in Submit Page:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.anrede',data:'{anrede}')}
```

throws the following error:

> TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\CObjectViewHelper::getContentObjectRenderer():
> Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface, null given,
> called in /var/www/html/site/vendor/typo3/cms-fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/CObjectViewHelper.php on line 130

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: I would have guessed that a `FluidStandaloneView ` is used in which the request is not set. But Powermail does that: 
https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/blob/master/Classes/Domain/Service/Mail/SendMailService.php#L365

Comment: Hi Julian, seems that you are on the right path ... in fact i use the cObject in the user mail and in the frontend output. In the user mail it works, but not in the frontend output. The frontend output uses this: https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/blob/a6e5d927d74ba2454821484b57601958a53cbb72/Classes/Utility/TemplateUtility.php#L98 and here the request is missing.

Comment: looks like the problem is already in the issue tracker: https://github.com/in2code-de/powermail/issues/990